# working an array into my script

Tags: arrays, bash, nested-loops

Here's what I want to do.  I have a Samba shared directory with several sub-directories. The structure is like this:

```
/srv/samba/Docutrack/3200/controls
                    ./3200/census
                    ./3200/stat
                    ./3400/controls
                    ./3400/census...etc
```

You get the point.  What I want to do with a nested loop is go through all sub-Docutrack level sub-directories and re-name all documents in ls with a command i've already put together. Once renamed all documents in ls will then be copied to a temp directory for compression and archival at the end of the day. The original documents will then be moved off to a CIFS share of it's particular designation.

I have this working on a per directory basis right now, but as we have 20 different facilities (3200, 3400, 3700...etc) with 9 sub-directories each, this will be MUCH easier if I can just add facility id's and sub-directories as we take on new locations. I took a Linux course for my Linux+ but have not had scripting experience until this month. I'm really enjoying it, but without much knowledge of nested loops and how the syntax works in bash i'd like to run it by everyone here.

Here's an example of what i'm working with right now.  It's not pretty, but hopefully you can guide me where i'm going wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /srv/samba/Docutrack/;

declare -a FacArr=("3200","3300","3400",3700")
declare -a FldArr=("controls","census","stat","issues")
Prefix= "Fac_`$FacArr[i]`_`$FldArr[j]`_"`date +_%b_%d_%Y,%H.%M.%S`"
target=/srv/samba/temp;

for i in ${FacArr[@]}
   for j in ${FldArr[@]}
do mv $file ${Prefix}_${file}
```

the end file after the rename will look something like this:

```
"Fac_3700_controls__Aug_27_2013,12.05.01_SFTP_test_2.txt"
 "Fac_3400_stat__Aug_27_2013,12.05.01_SFTP_test_2.txt"
```

Thanks so much for any help you can give!

**EDIT**
So I can clarify a little, here's the scrip that successfully does what i want on a per directory basis:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd into working path, all file paths will be relative to this path
cd /srv/samba/Docutrack/3700/controls;

# Set your variables
target=/srv/samba/temp;

# Rename all docs in current directory
for file in `ls`
do 
  mv $file "Fac_3700_controls_"`date +_%b_%d_%Y,%H.%M.%S`${file}
done

# Copy recursively the folders you need to the $target/ directory
cp -a /srv/samba/Docutrack/3700/controls/. $target/;


# Move renamed documents to distination directory
mv /srv/samba/Docutrack/3700/controls/* /media/controls/
```

**EDIT2**

Here's the current script I have.  It runs with no errors, but doesn't actually do anything.  No files are renamed, none are copied and none are moved.  I'm not sure why it's completing without errors but not succeeding. I'll continue to work on it tomorrow.  Thanks again everybody for your help!

```
/bin/bash

cd /srv/samba/Docutrack/

FacArr=('3200' '3300' '3400' '3700')
FldArr=('controls' 'census' 'stat' 'issues')
prefixDate=$(date +_%b_%d_%Y,%H.%M.%S_)
target=/srv/samba/temp

for i in ${FacArr[@]}; do
    for j in ${FldArr[@]}; do
        for file in "/${FacArr[i]}/${FldArr[j]}/"*; do
            mv "$file" "/Fac_${FacArr[i]}_${FldArr[j]}_${prefixDate}_${file}"
               cp -a /srv/samba/Docutrack/${FacArr[i]}/${FldArr[j]}/. $target/
            mv /srv/samba/Docutrack/${FacArr[i]}/${FldArr[j]}/* /${FacArr[i]}/ ${FldArr[j]}/
        done
    done
done
```

**FINAL EDIT**

I finally got my script worked out.  Thanks to everyone for all of your help.  I narrowed it down to what I thought might be the issue and got all of my variable parsing issues straightened out.  Here's the final script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#cd /srv/samba/Docutrack/
#
FacArr=('3200' '3300' '3400' '3700')
FldArr=('billing_pa' 'census' 'controls' 'delivery' 'discharge_dc' 'issues' 'med_recs' 'new_admit' 'new_orders' 'refills' 'stat')
prefixDate=$(date +_%b_%d_%Y.%H.%M.%S)
target=/srv/samba/temp/
#
for i in ${FacArr[@]}; do
     for j in ${FldArr[@]}; do
        cd "/srv/samba/Docutrack/""$i"/"$j"/
        for file in ` ls `; do
            mv $file "Fac_""$i""_""$j""_${prefixDate}_""$file"
            cp -a ` ls `  $target
            mv ` ls ` "/media/""$j"/
         done
    done
done
```

Comment: Comment 1: you don't need semicolons at end of lines.

Comment: Comment 2: your task is a complex one, but your problem might not be. Could you either simplify your problem description to only keep what's relevant to the actual problem (I do realize that's not as easy as it sounds) or be more specific in what you intended your script to do, what it actually did and why that's not what you want?

Comment: I believe that it did nothing, too many errors.

Comment: Comment 3: this might not be relevant to your task, but please take note that bash allows you to “glob” multiple directory levels at once.  For example try this: `ls /srv/samba/Docutrack/*/*`

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast response JB.  I was unaware of the glob function, but that sounds like exactly what i'm looking for.  I'll be using it frequently now.
To TL;DR my question, I need to have a nested loop to go through a series of parent directories, and have all documents in a series of sub-directories renamed with my time-date stamp then copied to a target location and then moved after the copy to a CIFS share.  All of this has been accomplished in a standard script, but said script would have to be created for every parent directory and sub-directory.  This would take too long.

Comment: Instead of ``for file in ` ls `; do`` use ``for file in *; do``. Quote your ``"$file"`` and ``"$target"``. Use ``mv * "/media/$j/"`` instead of ``mv ` ls ` "/media/""$j"/``. Also quote array in for like this ``for i in "${FacArr[@]}"; do``. All these are to solve a problem that will definitely appear if your files have space characters or newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that work for you?

```
cd /srv/samba/Docutrack/

FacArr=('3200' '3300' '3400' '3700')
FldArr=('controls' 'census' 'stat' 'issues')
prefixDate=$(date +_%b_%d_%Y,%H.%M.%S)
target=/srv/samba/temp

for i in "${FacArr[@]}"; do
    for j in "${FldArr[@]}"; do
        for file in "${FacArr[i]}/${FldArr[j]}/"*; do
            mv "$file" "$target/Fac_${FacArr[i]}_${FldArr[j]}_${prefixDate}_${file}"
        done
    done
done
```

Did I get it right that you want to place these files into `$target` directory?

Comment: This looks like it would work perfectly.  I in all actuality am not looking to move the documents in the mv command, only to rename them to the same directory.  Following that, i'll recursively copy all of the renamed docs to the $target dir for later archival and do a final mv to a CIFS share.

I run the script and it doesn't error out, but it doesn't rename or move any documents either.  The script looks correct though, as far as I can tell.